# Writing unit vector r in terms of sine and cosine?

Tags: vectors

In my physics II class our professor has us go through through three steps to find the unit vector $\hat r$:

Write the vector $\vec r$

$$\vec r=5\hat i + 5\hat j$$

Find the distance $r$ using Pythagorean's Theorum
$$r=\sqrt{5^2 + 5^2}\approx7.1$$

Then divide each component of $\vec r$ by $r$.
$$\hat r=\frac 5 {7.1}\hat i+\frac 5 {7.1}\hat j\approx.70\hat i+.70\hat j$$

Then we'll solve the equation to find the magnitude and multiply it by $\hat r$
For example the formulas look like $$\vec E= \frac {Kq} {r^2} \hat r$$

From what I understand this is just writing the vector in x and y components, so couldn't $\hat r$ be written as $\hat r=\cos x \hat i+\sin x \hat j$?

Comment: To your last question: yes.

Comment: @Lovsovs No, because that assumes that $\hat r$ has unit length.

Comment: @Théophile Well, that is standard notation, no? As OP uses it, it also seems to imply that it is of unit length?

Comment: So far we've only been shown $\hat r$ has unit length.

Comment: I see. I didn't notice that there was an $\hat r$ and an $\vec r$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can write your vector in polar form, and since $\hat r$ is by definition a unit vector, it will have the form you mentioned:

$$\hat r = \cos\theta\hat i + \sin\theta\hat j$$

for some angle $\theta$. Whether this is better or worse than the rectangular form $\hat r = a\hat i + b\hat j$ is a question of context.

I wonder why you are dividing by $r$ in your equation for $\vec E$ since the magnitude has already been factored out of $\vec r$, but perhaps there is a good reason for this; I don't know the context.

Comment: Incidentally, you have a rounding error in your question. You've calculated $\frac5{7.1} \approx 0.70$, but using the exact value you would get $\frac5{5\sqrt2} = \frac1{\sqrt2} = \frac{\sqrt2}2 \approx 0.71$. In mathematics you would typically use the simplified exact value, i.e., $\frac{\sqrt2}2$, to avoid this kind of error.

Comment: Is $R$ representing the magnitude in your equation? We have only been shown using $\hat r$ with unit length, so I'm assuming your notation is a scalar (magnitude) multiplied by the vector $\hat r$.

Comment: I see. I had misread your notation; I've updated my answer.

Comment: There was actually an error I only noticed once you mentioned it, but it should be $r^2$.  That is the equation for the magnitude of the electric field of a point charge at a point with distance $r$ from the charge creating the electric field.  I'm not sure why the professor uses the method described above myself, as it seems to just add more work, which is why i would prefer to use the notation described.

Comment: That makes sense. When it comes down to it, though, it will probably be at least as much work to use your method. If you have, say, $\vec r = 3\hat i + 4\hat j$, then you can very quickly get $\hat r = \frac35\hat i + \frac34\hat j$. But to express it in polar form, you must calculate $\theta = \text{atan2}(4,3) \approx 0.927$ (or $\theta \approx 53.1^\circ$). Is it really simpler to write $\hat r \approx \cos53.1^\circ\hat i + \sin53.1^\circ\hat j$?

Comment: Well I spent my whole physics I class using the trig functions for calculating $\theta$ and the vector components, so it's something I'm well familiar with.

Comment: @Théophile If r is not a unit vector then would I need to divide r by the magntude of r ?

Comment: @gansub It's hard to answer your question in the absence of context, but if you're looking for a unit vector, then yes, divide by the magnitude.